# How to link html back to the script - Uploading Script Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I initially saw this code online, that allows users to upload files to their google drive through a page. The script automatically creates a folder

//https://script.google.com/d/12EnDFZrsfpBubZ9lM7pnHIsn9M49_vyXm0TLBQ_pyx_ViAJH3HXgkoe9/edit?newcopy=true

So you will notice that initially the codes is supposed to be deployed as a webapp but I tweaked it to make it run on the sidebar. The html part loads fine, you can actually key in all the data, but once you click the upload form, it just returns a blank page. I'm pretty convinced that it's because the click button is not connecting to the script again, making it fail

This is the original code

```
/* The script is deployed as a web app and renders the form */
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
// This is important as file upload fail in IFRAME Sandbox mode.
}

/* This function will process the submitted form */
function uploadFiles(form) {

 try {

 // Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved 
    var dropbox = "Database";
;
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

// Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist 
if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

// Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob 
var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

// Set the file description as the name of the uploader 
file.setName(form.myCode + " "  + form.myfilename + " - " + form.myID + " - " + form.myName); 
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName + " - " + form.myEmail);

// Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive 
return "File uploaded successfully, please check your drive with this link for confirmation: " + file.getUrl();

 } catch (error) {

// If there's an error, show the error message 
return error.toString();
}

}
```

AND THE HTML IS HERE

```html
<!-- Include the Google CSS package -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
 
<!-- You can also include your own CSS styles -->
<style>
  form { margin: 40px 20px auto; }
  input { display:inline-block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
 
<script>
  
  // The function will be called after the form is submitted
  function uploadFile() {
    document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = "Uploading File..";
    google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
       .uploadFiles(document.getElementById("labnol"));
    return false;
  }
 
  // This function will be called after the Google Script has executed
  function fileUploaded(status) {
    document.getElementById('labnol').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
  }
  
</script>
 
<!-- This is the HTML form -->
<form id="labnol">
 
  <!-- Text input fields -->
  File Upload<br>
  <br>
  Your Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name.."> <br><br>
  Email Address: <br>
  <input type="email" name="myEmail" placeholder="Your email.."> <br><br>
  ID? <br>
  <input type="number" name="myID" placeholder="Your ID.."> <br><br>
  Upload Code: <br>
  <input type="text" name="myCode" placeholder="Your Upload code.."> <br><br>
  File Name: <br>
  <input type="text" name="myfilename" placeholder="Your File Name">  <br><br>
 
  <!-- File input filed -->
  <input type="file" name="myFile">
 
  <!-- The submit button. It calls the server side function uploadfiles() on click -->
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="uploadFile" value="Upload File" 
         onclick="this.value='Uploading..';uploadFile();">
 
</form>
 
<!-- Here the results of the form submission will be displayed -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

So from the original code I tweaked it to replace the top part

```
function showSidebar() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
  .setTitle('Upload Form')
  .setWidth(250);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
}

// This function will process the submitted form 
function uploadFile(form) {

 try {

// Name of the Drive folder where the files should be saved 
    var dropbox = "Database";
 ;
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

  // Find the folder, create if the folder does not exist 
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

// Get the file uploaded though the form as a blob 
var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    

// Set the file description as the name of the uploader 
file.setName(form.myCode + " "  + form.myfilename + " - " + form.myID + " - " + form.myName); 
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName + " - " + form.myEmail);

// Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive 
return "File uploaded successfully, please check your drive with this link for confirmation: " + file.getUrl();

 } catch (error) {

 // If there's an error, show the error message 
return error.toString();
 }

}
```

So I basically replaced the top part with a script to load the sidebar and the html "form" but the error appears is that upon clicking upload, it does not work.

I'm guessing it's this part

```
 <input type="submit" id="uploadFile" value="Upload File" 
     onclick="this.value='Uploading..';uploadFile();">
```

since `onClick`, it should run the function `uploadFile()` but it does not work.
I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time but can't seem to make this last part work. So I'm here asking if anyone can help me solve this coding issues

Answer (score 0):

Based from this documentation: HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions

> [**`google.script.run`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that allows HTML-service pages to call server-side Apps Script functions. The following example shows the most basic functionality of **`google.script.run`** — [calling a function on the server](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)) from client-side JavaScript.

Check how the [Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) communicates with Apps Script. If you call a server function with a form element as a parameter, the form becomes a single object with field names as keys and field values as values. The values are all converted to strings, except for the contents of file-input fields, which become [**`Blob`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob) objects.

Here is there sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
      }
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="myFile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It would be best if you simplify how you call the function in an `OnSubmit` event. Also, you can debug you script using [Execution Transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#execution_transcript), which is a record of each call to a Google Apps Script service that is made while the script runs.

Hope this helps!